# How to rewrite QuoteManagement in magento 2

Tags: magento2, quote

I'm trying to extend the class "QuoteManagement", but when I try to make the payment, an error is returned.

**My code:**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement" type="Multicategoria\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement" />
</config>
```

**module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Multicategoria_Quote" setup_version="1.0.0" />
     <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
             <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
            <module name="Magento_Quote"/>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>>
        </sequence>
</config>
```

**New class:**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Multicategoria\Quote\Model;


use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement as MagentoQuoteManagement;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface as EventManager;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface;


/**
 * Class QuoteManagement
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.TooManyFields)
 */
//class QuoteManagement implements \Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface
class QuoteManagement extends MagentoQuoteManagement
{

     /**
     * @var EventManager
     */
    protected $eventManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $quoteRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
     */
    protected $checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @var QuoteFactory
     */
    protected $quoteFactory;

    /**
     * @param EventManager $eventManager 
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository 
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession 
     * @param QuoteFactory $quoteFactory 
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        EventManager $eventManager,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository, 
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession, 
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory
    ) {
        $this->eventManager = $eventManager; 
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository; 
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession; 
        $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory; 
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function placeOrder($cartId, PaymentInterface $paymentMethod = null)
    {
        $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);

        $paymentMethodString = $quote->getPayment()->getMethod(); // edit 19.10.17

        // get data from addresses and remove ids
        $billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress()->getData();
        $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getData();
        unset($billingAddress['id']);
        unset($billingAddress['quote_id']);
        unset($shippingAddress['id']);
        unset($shippingAddress['quote_id']);

        $itemsPerVendor = [];
        foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
            // I don't know how do you keep track of your product vendor, use this as reference only
            $product_id = $item->getProduct()->getId();
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);

            $itemsPerVendor[$product->getSellerId()][] = $item;
        }

        foreach($itemsPerVendor as $vendor => $items) {
            // init Quote Split
            $quoteSplit = $this->quoteFactory->create();
            $quoteSplit->setStoreId($quote->getStoreId());
            $quoteSplit->setCustomer($quote->getCustomer());
            $quoteSplit->setCustomerIsGuest($quote->getCustomerIsGuest());
            if ($quote->getCheckoutMethod() === self::METHOD_GUEST) {
                $quoteSplit->setCustomerEmail($quote->getBillingAddress()->getEmail());
                $quoteSplit->setCustomerGroupId(\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupInterface::NOT_LOGGED_IN_ID);
            }

            // save quoteSplit in order to have a quote id for item
            $this->quoteRepository->save($quoteSplit);

            foreach ($items as $item) {
                // add item
                $item->setId(null); // init item id for force to be added to quoteSplit collection
                $quoteSplit->addItem($item);
            }

            // set addresses
            $quoteSplit->getBillingAddress()->setData($billingAddress);
            $quoteSplit->getShippingAddress()->setData($shippingAddress);

            // recollect totals into the quote
            $quoteSplit->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals();

            // set payment method // edit 19.10.17
            $quoteSplit->getPayment()->setMethod($paymentMethodString);
            if ($paymentMethod) {
                $quoteSplit->getPayment()->setQuote($quoteSplit);
                $data = $paymentMethod->getData();
                $quoteSplit->getPayment()->importData($data);
            }

            // dispatch this event as Magento standard once per each quote split
            $this->eventManager->dispatch('checkout_submit_before', ['quote' => $quoteSplit]);
            $this->quoteRepository->save($quoteSplit);
            $order = $this->submit($quoteSplit);
            $orders[] = $order;

            if (null == $order) {
                throw new LocalizedException(
                    __('An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again.')
                );
            }


        // disable origin quote
        $quote->setIsActive(false);
        $this->quoteRepository->save($quote); // edit 19.10.17

        $this->checkoutSession->setLastQuoteId($quoteSplit->getId());
        $this->checkoutSession->setLastSuccessQuoteId($quoteSplit->getId());
        $this->checkoutSession->setLastOrderId($order->getId());
        $this->checkoutSession->setLastRealOrderId($order->getIncrementId());
        $this->checkoutSession->setLastOrderStatus($order->getStatus());

        $this->eventManager->dispatch('checkout_submit_all_after', ['orders' => $orders, 'quote' => $quote]);

    }
        /**
         * the API declaration and interface describe this function returning int, you can't return an array.
         * in order to do that you will have to create a new end point for that.
         */
        return "teste";
    }}
```

**Error:**

```
"Fatal Error: 'Uncaught Error: Call to a member function create() on null in \/opt\/lampp\/htdocs\/backendmulti\/vendor\/magento\/module-quote\/Model\/QuoteManagement.php:451\nStack trace:\n#0 \/opt\/lampp\/htdocs\/backendmulti\/vendor\/magento\/module-quote\/Model\/QuoteManagement.php(407): Magento\\Quote\\Model\\QuoteManagement->submitQuote(Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Interceptor), Array)\n#1 \/opt\/lampp\/htdocs\/backendmulti\/app\/code\/Multicategoria\/Quote\/Model\/QuoteManagement.php(130): Magento\\Quote\\Model\\QuoteManagement->submit(Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Interceptor))\n#2 \/opt\/lampp\/htdocs\/backendmulti\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(58): Multicategoria\\Quote\\Model\\QuoteManagement->placeOrder(43, NULL)\n#3 \/opt\/lampp\/htdocs\/backendmulti\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(138): Multicategoria\\Quote\\Model\\QuoteManagement\\Interceptor->___callParent('placeOrder', Array)\n#4 \/opt\/lampp\/htdocs\/backendmulti\/vendor\/magento\/module-braintree\/Plugin\/OrderCancellation.php(63): Multicategoria\\Quote\\Model\\QuoteM' in '\/opt\/lampp\/htdocs\/backendmulti\/vendor\/magento\/module-quote\/Model\/QuoteManagement.php' on line 451"
```

Can anyone help me fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove **__construct** from your overwrite class(Multicategoria\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement). Following part you should remove:

```
public function __construct(
    EventManager $eventManager,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository, 
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession, 
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory
) {
    $this->eventManager = $eventManager; 
    $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository; 
    $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession; 
    $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory; 
}
```

This is a totally wrong way without calling parent class **__construct**. Also, you access the same variable that already has in the parent class. So don't need to declare again here.

If you want still **__construct** in your class then try following code.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Multicategoria\Quote\Model;


use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement as MagentoQuoteManagement;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface as EventManager;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface;
use Magento\Authorization\Model\UserContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\ToOrder as ToOrderConverter;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\ToOrderAddress as ToOrderAddressConverter;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote as QuoteEntity;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem as ToOrderItemConverter;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment\ToOrderPayment as ToOrderPaymentConverter;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterfaceFactory as OrderFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface as OrderManagement;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteValidator;
use Magento\Quote\Model\CustomerManagement;

/**
 * Class QuoteManagement
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.TooManyFields)
 */
//class QuoteManagement implements \Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface
class QuoteManagement extends MagentoQuoteManagement
{
    public function __construct(
        EventManager $eventManager,
        QuoteValidator $quoteValidator,
        OrderFactory $orderFactory,
        OrderManagement $orderManagement,
        CustomerManagement $customerManagement,
        ToOrderConverter $quoteAddressToOrder,
        ToOrderAddressConverter $quoteAddressToOrderAddress,
        ToOrderItemConverter $quoteItemToOrderItem,
        ToOrderPaymentConverter $quotePaymentToOrderPayment,
        UserContextInterface $userContext,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerModelFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\AddressFactory $quoteAddressFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface $accountManagement,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteIdMaskFactory $quoteIdMaskFactory = null,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $eventManager,
            $quoteValidator,
            $orderFactory,
            $orderManagement,
            $customerManagement,
            $quoteAddressToOrder,
            $quoteAddressToOrderAddress,
            $quoteItemToOrderItem,
            $quotePaymentToOrderPayment,
            $userContext,
            $quoteRepository,
            $customerRepository,
            $customerModelFactory,
            $quoteAddressFactory,
            $dataObjectHelper,
            $storeManager,
            $checkoutSession,
            $customerSession,
            $accountManagement,
            $quoteFactory,
            $quoteIdMaskFactory,
            $addressRepository
        );
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function placeOrder($cartId, PaymentInterface $paymentMethod = null)
    {
        $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);

        $paymentMethodString = $quote->getPayment()->getMethod(); // edit 19.10.17

        // get data from addresses and remove ids
        $billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress()->getData();
        $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getData();
        unset($billingAddress['id']);
        unset($billingAddress['quote_id']);
        unset($shippingAddress['id']);
        unset($shippingAddress['quote_id']);

        $itemsPerVendor = [];
        foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
            // I don't know how do you keep track of your product vendor, use this as reference only
            $product_id = $item->getProduct()->getId();
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);

            $itemsPerVendor[$product->getSellerId()][] = $item;
        }

        foreach($itemsPerVendor as $vendor => $items) {
            // init Quote Split
            $quoteSplit = $this->quoteFactory->create();
            $quoteSplit->setStoreId($quote->getStoreId());
            $quoteSplit->setCustomer($quote->getCustomer());
            $quoteSplit->setCustomerIsGuest($quote->getCustomerIsGuest());
            if ($quote->getCheckoutMethod() === self::METHOD_GUEST) {
                $quoteSplit->setCustomerEmail($quote->getBillingAddress()->getEmail());
                $quoteSplit->setCustomerGroupId(\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupInterface::NOT_LOGGED_IN_ID);
            }

            // save quoteSplit in order to have a quote id for item
            $this->quoteRepository->save($quoteSplit);

            foreach ($items as $item) {
                // add item
                $item->setId(null); // init item id for force to be added to quoteSplit collection
                $quoteSplit->addItem($item);
            }

            // set addresses
            $quoteSplit->getBillingAddress()->setData($billingAddress);
            $quoteSplit->getShippingAddress()->setData($shippingAddress);

            // recollect totals into the quote
            $quoteSplit->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals();

            // set payment method // edit 19.10.17
            $quoteSplit->getPayment()->setMethod($paymentMethodString);
            if ($paymentMethod) {
                $quoteSplit->getPayment()->setQuote($quoteSplit);
                $data = $paymentMethod->getData();
                $quoteSplit->getPayment()->importData($data);
            }

            // dispatch this event as Magento standard once per each quote split
            $this->eventManager->dispatch('checkout_submit_before', ['quote' => $quoteSplit]);
            $this->quoteRepository->save($quoteSplit);
            $order = $this->submit($quoteSplit);
            $orders[] = $order;

            if (null == $order) {
                throw new LocalizedException(
                    __('An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again.')
                );
            }


            // disable origin quote
            $quote->setIsActive(false);
            $this->quoteRepository->save($quote); // edit 19.10.17

            $this->checkoutSession->setLastQuoteId($quoteSplit->getId());
            $this->checkoutSession->setLastSuccessQuoteId($quoteSplit->getId());
            $this->checkoutSession->setLastOrderId($order->getId());
            $this->checkoutSession->setLastRealOrderId($order->getIncrementId());
            $this->checkoutSession->setLastOrderStatus($order->getStatus());

            $this->eventManager->dispatch('checkout_submit_all_after', ['orders' => $orders, 'quote' => $quote]);

        }
        /**
         * the API declaration and interface describe this function returning int, you can't return an array.
         * in order to do that you will have to create a new end point for that.
         */
        return "teste";
    }
}
```

*You can do this using plugin without overwriting whole class.*